# Docker installing wrong django packages

Tags: django, docker

Host Machine: WIndows 10

I created a django project that uses an sqlite database. I tried to put my django app in a container using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5


#Enviromental variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#Work Dir
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Dockercompose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    volumes:
     - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Now, when I try to run the code it gives me this error:

```
Starting iomweb_db_1 ... done
Starting iomweb_web_1 ... done
Attaching to iomweb_db_1, iomweb_web_1
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:15.535 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:15.535 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:15.547 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.
5432"
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:15.576 UTC [19] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018
-12-31 19:58:19 UTC
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:16.655 UTC [19] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic
recovery in progress
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:16.662 UTC [19] LOG:  redo starts at 0/17ABE00
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:16.662 UTC [19] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/17ABE38: wanted 24, got 0
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:16.662 UTC [19] LOG:  redo done at 0/17ABE00
db_1   | 2018-12-31 20:26:16.716 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wh
eel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip
install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-
install-from-pypi>.
web_1  |   """)
web_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wh
eel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip
install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-
install-from-pypi>.
web_1  |   """)
web_1  | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4e1a0
75268>
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrap
per
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
 line 112, in inner_run
web_1  |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in rais
e_last_exception
web_1  |     raise _exception[1]
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327,
 in execute
web_1  |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrap
per
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
web_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populat
e
web_1  |     app_config.import_models()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_mo
dels
web_1  |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 206, in <module>

web_1  |     class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 222, in Registra
tionProfile
web_1  |     user = models.OneToOneField(UserModelString(), verbose_name=_('user'))
```

Now, I can manually fix this problem inside of the container under the models; but I am not sure where the docker container is getting these models from. I tried to change the models from the python in the system but still doing this. I would like to fix this so I do not have to fix this manually every time I build this container. I could do a docker commit; but still any help to find out why docker is taking this models.py from.

Comment: maybe you can try to delete all the pyc files and try to build and run the dockers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. The problem was that django-registration-redux library that I was installing was not compatible with Django 2.0. Once I updated this package to the latest version it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the same error but adding this to my docker file fixed the problem:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        tzdata \
        libopencv-dev \
        build-essential \
        libssl-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
        libexpat1-dev \
        gettext \
        unzip \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-pip \
        python3-dev \
        python3-venv \
        git \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    \
```

It installs a lot of packages but the error was solved

Answer (score -1):

Create a `run.sh` file and write below;

```
python manage.py makemigrations && \
python manage.py migrate && \
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And in you `docker-compose.yml` file write below;

```
...
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh run.sh
...
```

Comment: Did that and still getting the on_delete missing from models.py on /python35/site-packages/registration/models.py